# Client can't open service on Win8

Tags: c#, wcf

I use WSHttpBinding for may wcf app. And I have a problem when I try running client on Windows 8.1 (not Pro). The application crashed every time when run Service.Open()

Binding configuration:

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 524288; 
binding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
```

For other operating system it's work well.

**Exception message**: An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.

**Inner exception**: Security validation error message.

Comment: Catch the exception and read the error message?

Answer (score 1):

> Metro apps (win 8) support following WCF bindings:
>
> - BasicHttpBinding
> - NetTcpBinding
> - NetHttpBinding
> - CustomBinding
>
> **WSHttpBinding** is not supported!

In win 8.1 win **WSHttpBinding** does work and should be used, because Microsoft have enhanced the security in the LSAS in 8.1 / 2012 R2 and BasicHttpBinding should fail due to it is no longer supported for sending the users identity information over the network.

I am guessing you are using **WSHttpBinding** same way - you want to use username/password and send them over network.

Your case should be : [Message Security with a User Name Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731058(v=vs.110).aspx)
[image]

I exactly do no know what the problem is, but it seems to be **trust issues**. Your error is thrown because your **security validation fails** in validation.

If program worked on **win 8.1 pro** and not **win 8.1**:

- and you use username + certificate to validate then reinstall certificate
- and you use username + password to validate then check if domain user exists and if it tries to connect with the right domain.

Other then that I would be some fluke chance like :

- certificate does not exit
- certificate does not have privileges needed
- certificate is based on some other certificates that is invalid, uninstalled, expired or ...
- certificate or it's base certificates use algorithm that is not supported

Comment: Yes, you're right. I use this binding for authorization.

Comment: I use username + password to validate. Username and password take from database. For the testing we use OpenSSl-generated certificate. The certificate not installed on the client machine I use file with openkey token.